# jQuery Validate custom method not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Can someone explain to me why this is not hitting my helper function? Not sure if it's a syntax thing or what..

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("expDateExistInPast", function (value) {
    return customFunction(value);
}, "Expiration cannot exist in past.");

$("form[name='myForm']").validate({
 rules: {
    exp: {expDateExistInPast: true}
 }, 
 messages: {
     exp: {
        required: "message", 
        expDateExistInPast: "otherMsg"
    }
 }, 
  submitHandler: function (form) {
       form.submit();
  }
})


function customFunction(value) {
    alert("magic here");
}
```

**UPDATE** - Adding HTML

```
<input class="myClass" type="text" name="expiration" id="exp" maxlength="4" pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9]$" required="" placeholder="MMYY" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the relevant HTML, because everything in your OP is working perfectly fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/se4dc18h/

Comment: added HTML above. just a little info on this, I'm expecting a MMYY date value from the user. Hence the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` contains `name="expiration"`...

```
<input class="myClass" type="text" name="expiration" id="exp" maxlength="4" pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[0-9][0-9]$" required="" placeholder="MMYY" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

However, the problem is that your `.validate()` method is using `exp` within the `rules` object...

```
rules: {
    exp: {
        expDateExistInPast: true
    }
},
```

---

You **must** only use the `name` attribute here...

```
rules: {
    expiration: { // <- this is the NAME of the input
        expDateExistInPast: true
    }
},
```

**Working:  [jsfiddle.net/se4dc18h/](http://jsfiddle.net/se4dc18h/)**